# Django Make dynamic delete Function

Tags: python, django

I have a **`views.py`** file like this

```
def delete_post(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    post = models.Post.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'system/ajax/delete.html', {'post': post})

class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy("system:post_list")
```

and my **`urls.py`** file looks like:

```
url(r'^post-list/$',views.PostList.as_view(),name='post_list'),
url(r'^post-delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.PostDelete.as_view(),name='post_delete'),
url(r'^ajax/delete/$',views.delete_data,name='ajax_delete_data'),
```

my **`delete.html`** look like this:

```
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_post' pk=data.pk %}">
      {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">
  </form>
```

my **`post_list.html`** is the following:

```
<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-url="{% url 'system:ajax_delete_data' %}" type="button" class="delete-post" >
    delete
</button>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.delete-post',function(){ 
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:{
            'id':id,
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#delete-data').html(data);
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

in my script its only can delete one data model called `post`, I want to make it dynamic, so I don't need to write many functions.

on this

```
post = models.Post.objects.get(id=id) <---
```

any have a suggestion?

Comment: You here seem to do the `delete` in two ways: with a `DeleteView`, and with a function.

Comment: can you explain?... here i know `def delete_post(request):` just for call the delete template into `listview` since I use twitter modal, see `delete.html` submit button go to `class PostDelete(DeleteView):`

Comment: Do you want to deleted more than one records at a time?